# How can I combine the above two steps in one using loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I was doing this:

```
# poLCA
library(poLCA)
data("carcinoma")

# save LCA modle index for different k class 
gc.AIC <- data.frame()
gc.BIC <- data.frame()
f <- cbind(A, B, C ,D ,E, F, G) ~ 1 

for (i in 2:4) {
  lc <- poLCA(f, carcinoma, nclass = i)
  gc.AIC<-  rbind(gc.AIC, cbind(i, (lc$aic)))
  gc.BIC<-  rbind(gc.BIC, cbind(i, (lc$bic)))
}

# svae LCA modle for different k class
lc <- list()

for (i in 2:4) {
  lc[i] <- poLCA(f, carcinoma, nclass = i)
}
```

If it is a large data, I need to repeat it twice, which is very time-consuming.
How can I combine the above two steps in one loop process?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
lc <- list()
for (i in 2:4) {
      lc[[i]] <- poLCA(f, carcinoma, nclass = i)

      gc.AIC<-  rbind(gc.AIC, cbind(i, (lc[[i]]$aic)))
      gc.BIC<-  rbind(gc.BIC, cbind(i, (lc[[i]]$bic)))
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the code is easy to understand and do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply`.

```
i <- 2:4
lc <- lapply(i, \(i) poLCA::poLCA(f, carcinoma, nclass=i, verbose=FALSE))
```

Extract AIC and BIC later.

```
data.frame(i, t(sapply(lc, `[`, c('aic', 'bic'))))
#   i      aic      bic
# 1 2 664.5137 706.0739
# 2 3   633.41 697.1357
# 3 4 640.5717 726.4629
```

---

*Data:*

```
data("carcinoma", package='poLCA')
```

Comment: Thank you! I never thought of using lapply and sapply.
They are a bit abstract to me, maybe I should learn their functions

Comment: @Bruce `lapply` comes from list-apply, and applies a function to a list (data frames are special kinds of lists). the function applied is the bracket function `\`[\`()` that you know e.g. from `data[, 1]`. `sapply` is actually just `lapply` but tries to coerce the result into a matrix (which works fine in this case). There are neat toy examples in the documentation, just type `?lapply`.

Comment: Thank for your note for this function. It's explain very details!!!